# Sum of powers of $3$ modulo $8$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> What is $(3^1+3^2+\cdots+3^{2015})\bmod{8}?$

I'm really bad at these kinds of problems so a thorough explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Your title cannot be the body of your post. Write the problem in the body.

Answer (score 3):

As a hint, 
\begin{align}
3^1 &\equiv 3 \pmod 8\\
3^2 &\equiv 1\pmod 8\\
3^3 &\equiv 3\pmod 8 \\
3^4 &\equiv 1\pmod 8\\
\end{align}

This gives a pattern $(3+1+3+1+\cdots) \bmod 8$ in your sum.

Comment: Oh, I see! So then since $3^1+3^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot{3^{2014}}$ would contain $1007 $ 3's and $1007 $ 1's and since 2015 is odd we will just add another three and the answer would be $4031$

Comment: Taken modulo 8.

Comment: Gotcha, so it's 7. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $3^1+3^2+\cdots+3^{2015}=\dfrac{3^{2016}-3}{3^1-1}=\dfrac{3^{2016}-3}{2}=\dfrac{3^{2(1008)}-3}{2}\equiv $ what? (mod $8$)

Comment: Did you mean $3^{2016}-3^1$?

Comment: I have edited it, thanks!

Comment: I'm kinda new to sums and modular arithmetic so I'm curious as to how you determined that $$\sum_{n=1}^{2015}{3^n}$$ was equal to $\frac{3^{2016}-3}{3^1-1}$

Comment: $3^1(3^1+ \dots + 3^{2015})-1(3^1+ \dots + 3^{2015})=3(3^{2015})+3(3^{2014})-3^{2015} \dots +3^1(3^1)-3^2-3^1=3^{2016}-3$

Comment: it's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

As $3$ has order $2\bmod 8$, you have
$$3^n\equiv\begin{cases}3&\text{if }n\text{ is odd},\\
1&\text{if }n\text{ is even}.
\end{cases}$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2015}3^k\equiv3\times(\text{number of odd integers}\le 2015)+(\text{number of even integers}\le2014)\mod 8.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $3^1+3^2+\cdots+3^{2015}=\dfrac{3^{2016}-3}{2}$

and $16|3^4-1$ so $16|(3^4)^{504}-1$ so $8|\dfrac{3^{2016}-1}{2}=\dfrac{3^{2016}-3}{2}+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different take.

Let $x_n = 3^1+3^2+\cdots+3^{n}$. Then $x_{n+1}=3x_n+3$, with $x_0=0$.

Modulo $8$ we get a periodic sequence of period $4$:
$$
0,3,4,7,0,3,4,7\dots
$$
Therefore, $x_{2015} = x_{2015 \bmod 4} = x_3 = 7$.